# display data on gridview accordingly to current login user not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

How do you actually display data that is retrieved from database according to the current login user? I used this method but it is actually not working. Where have i gone wrong?

My .cs code:

```
 int selectedRow = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[selectedRow];
    int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);

    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ASPNETDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    string strCommandText = "SELECT date, starttime, endtime, planner FROM bookings WHERE UserId =@UserId";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

    myConnect.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", UserId);

    reader.Close();
    myConnect.Close();
```

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting an exception? Wrong results? Something else?

Comment: There isn't any error. When i booked my appointment previously in the first .aspx page, and i proceed on to the view appointment page, i should be able to see all my previously booked appointment and the one that i recently booked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, you are executing the DataReader BEFORE you add the UserId parameter. In fact, it's a good idea not even to open the connection until your command object is fully defined.

It should look more like this:

```
string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ASPNETDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    string strCommandText = "SELECT date, starttime, endtime, planner FROM bookings WHERE UserId =@UserId";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", UserId);

    myConnect.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
    myGridView.DataSource = reader;
    myGridView.DataBind();

    reader.Close();
    myConnect.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to inverse lines:

```
       myConnect.Open();
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", UserId);
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

;-)